# classical probability question

Tags: probability

At the race course, Adam meets his friend Bruce. Bruce offers to receive 
bets from Adam for a race involved two horses named Gold and Diamond. 
Bruce suggests even odds for betting on both horses.

However, a bookmaker also offers odds for the same race. The bookmaker 
gives odds of 3 to 1 for Gold and 0.5 to 1 for Diamond.

Not to disappoint Bruce, Adam has decided to place bets with the 
bookmaker, as well as with his friend Bruce.

Adam has \$10 in his pocket and is considering the following strategies:

(I) Bet \$4 for Gold  with the bookmaker and \$6 for Diamond with 
Bruce.

(II) Bet \$5 for Gold with Bruce and \$5 for Diamond with the 
bookmaker.

(III) Bet \$6 for Gold with Bruce and \$4 for Diamond with the 
bookmaker.

(IV) Bet \$7 for Gold with the bookmaker and \$3 for Diamond with 
Bruce.

Which strategy is preferable if Adam’s foremost goal is to minimize the 
possibility of any loss?

A. (I) 
 B. (II) 
 C. (III) 
 D. (IV)

E. It does not matter. Adam should just randomly choose a strategy

Comment: Are these British odds or mathematical odds? In other words, do the bookmaker's odds suggest Diamond or Gold is the odds-on favorite?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is A. 
If Gold wins, Adam gets 4*4=16 from bookmaker. If Gold loses, Adam gets 6*2=12 from Bruce. He puts in 10, so he is always ahead.